# Unable to fix garbage url

Tags: wordpress, url, http-status-code-404

I am having a problem http://prntscr.com/587iwz
Generally any garbage/wrong URL should goto 404 page but in my case, it is going to some uploading page.
I am using Presscore theme.

Answer (score 1):

Take a list of plugins and figure out the suspected plugins.. you could put a temporary maintenance plugin... or else check by deactivating the plugins when the traffic is less to website. Theme appears to be no issue. Then the possible problem could be either .htaccess or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Find that particular link in your web files and replace it, that's it.

You can use notepad++ or similar programs to search text in multiple files. My advice to you would be to not use nulled themes downloaded from random websites

Comment: thanks sajid but the thing is that its just a garbage url and can be any like example.com/sdsdsd. i want to redirect to 404 page whenever a page isnt my in my database/website.

Comment: Had you purchased the theme or downloaded it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your .htaccess

Try adding this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/
```

or map them to one error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
```